Is this Pachyphytum leaf budding? If so, what do I do with it?
I have a pot with three succulents, which are doing fine thanks to some great advice here.
Whilst turning the pot a couple of weeks ago, I accidentally knocked a leaf Pachyphytums. I did a quick search, and it seems you can just lay these on the medium, and they should start to grow into a new plant.
I did that, and noticed today that it has two tiny red hair-like growths, that look like baby roots, and three little buds that look like they may be new leaves...

Can anyone confirm if I'm right, and if not, what these growths are? More to the point, what do I do with it? I'd like to grow this into a new plant if I can.
Thanks for any advice you can give.

Something makes you think they are roots?

@YosefBaskin Only that they look like roots. I described them that they "look like baby roots." I am happy for anyone to correct me. I just want to know how I get this to grow into a full plant. Thanks

Were the 'roots' near the soil and heading down? Or on the other side and heading up?

@YosefBaskin Ah, well there's a good question! I wanted to water the pot, so having read that cuttings should be left on the medium to dry, I picked it up so it wouldn't get too wet. It was only then that I noticed the growths, so I'm really not 100% sure which way up it was. I think, but cannot be certain that those red bits were pointing down, but I wouldn't bet my apple and honey on it!

Yep, that's a growing bud there! Gently press it on top of the soil with the red roots facing down, and keep it damp BUT NOT WET. More roots will grow and the tiny bud of leaves will get larger.

Thanks for the reply. Any idea how long it will take to grow? The others I have are looking fine, but haven't grown that much in the couple of years I've had them.
